# Closing of c# socket by shutdown method

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, shutdown

I have a strange problem. I have client socket application which connects to server (client applications run on PCs and server application runs on server as windows service). Problem occurs in this code which is called on server for every opened client socket during closing of server application:

```
socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
socket.Close();
socket.Dispose();
```

Code runs without any error and application is closed successfully but problem will appear in client application immediatelly after server application close.

This is the code of async callback method which is registered by method BeginReceive on client:

```
private void ReadMachineServiceResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    TcpServiceStateObject state = (TcpServiceStateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.WorkSocket;

    try
    {
        bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bytesRead = 0;

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            this.AddEventLogMessage(LogMessageType.Error, ex.Message, null, true, false);
        }));
    }

    try
    {
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            //do some code...
        }

        state = new TcpServiceStateObject();
        this._machineServiceSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(this.ReadMachineServiceResponse), state);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //do some exception code
    }
}
```

When server application is closed then method ReadMachineServiceResponse is called several times in one second until client application is closed. It was called for two days until client application was closed by user. I discovered that this method is called even in case when I disconnect client computer from network - so problem is on client side. Messages that are received on client side after shutdown method call are empty - variable bytesRead = 0. Socket property "Connected" is still set to true. Client doesn't know that connection was closed so exception isn't thrown.

When I was try to comment line "socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);" on server side then everything works correct. Exception was thrown on client side and any message wasn't received after closing of socket on server side.

Problem occurs everytime - it does not matter whether the client is connected to the server for a few seconds or several days, and whether the client receives some message from the server between the start and the end of the server run.

In netstat on client computer I can see that socket stays in CLOSE_WAIT state.

Thank you for every idea. I would like to know cause of this problem.

Comment: You shouldn't do a BeginReceive after a connection is closed.  You need to implement the BeginDisconnect : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx.  In theory you should never start a disconnect from the server so this shouldn't happen every time.  Occasionally a server will shutdown before client so you should attempt to prevent any errors from occurring by fixing this bug.

Comment: Socket programming requires careful compliance with all protocol rules. You need to study available documentation, including the [Winsock Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/) (most of which is applicable to any socket API). Neither endpoint should close the socket until they have each shutdown sending _and_ seen end-of-stream from the other endpoint (i.e. receive completed with 0 bytes). Note that a connection error (cable disconnect, endpoint process crashed, etc.) won't be detected until an endpoint tries to send data; this is by design and desirable behavior.

Comment: Also, contrary to the previous comment, it is fine for either endpoint of a connection to initiate the shutdown. But both endpoints do need to be carefully implemented to make sure they handle the graceful closure correctly (i.e. not close the socket until the right time). In any case, there's no good way to answer this question as stated; it's too broad a problem description and you haven't provided a good [mcve].